# Node Redis-OM: this[#schema].generateId is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Hi everyone I am trying to save an entinty into a redis repository, the driver is correctly connected the schema is created as edxpected same with the repo. The problem comes when I try to save the entity, The exception I am getting is: `TypeError: this[#schema].generateId is not a function at Repository.save`.

I already tried with other schema types of old redis-om version usind `Class Session extends Entity {}` but I get the same error every time.

the versión of `redis-node-om` is `0.4.3`.

Here I provide the code that isn't working:

### Middleware.js

```js
const sessionRepository = getSessionRepo(redisClient);
const session = createSessionObj(req);
console.log("[REDIS] **GUARDANDO DATOS EN EL REPOSITORIO DE REDIS**");
const storedSession = await sessionRepository.save(session);
```

### sessionSchema

```js
const sessionSchema = new Schema(
    "session",
    {
        userId: { type: "string", field: "user_id" },
        role: { type: "string", field: "user_role" },
        jwt: { type: "string", sortable: "yes", field: "user_jwt", weight: 1 },
    },
    { dataStructure: "HASH" }
);
```

### getSessionRepo function

```js
function getSessionRepo(redisClient) {
    console.log(sessionSchema);
    const sessionRepository = new Repository(sessionSchema, redisClient);
    console.log(sessionRepository);
    return sessionRepository;
}
```

### createSession function:

```js
function createSessionObj(req) {
    let session = {};
    session.userId = req.body.userId;
    session.role = req.body.role;
    session.jwt = req.body.tokenJWT;

    return session;
}
```

## EDIT: When calling save() and providing an ID

The error differs in this case: `'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')`

Comment: This looks correct to me. Can you try calling save by providing an ID and see if that works?